# Use and omission of the word "which"

Tags: relative-pronouns

> A diet rich in anti-oxidants, which, a number of nutritionists claim, may help to strengthen the immune system.

Is "which" necessary or why not?

Comment: Is it intended to be a complete sentence or a noun phrase?

Comment: Do you have a source? Not sure if it is proper writing style, but if you are trying to emphasize the pauses in speech, it seems OK. Otherwise leave out the comma after which.

Comment: @user3169 The commas are setting off the parenthetical *a number of nutritionists claim* from *which may help to strengthen the immune system*.

Comment: @user3169 You can't delete the comma before *a number of nutritionists claim* but leave the one after. Grammatically you must have both or neither.

Comment: Did you find this sentence, or did you compose it? Please provide the source if you found it somewhere, as the text before it is highly relevant, particularly if this is not the entire sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you leave out "which", the sentence makes sense.

With "which" present, it is grammatically incorrect.  It needs a further phrase after "the immune system".

e.g. A diet rich in anti-oxidants, which a number of nutritionists claim may help to strengthen the immune system, can be easily achieved by drinking copious amounts of red wine.